# Disassemble Executable Automatically in C++

Tags: c++, disassemblers

I have 2 types of files, namely benign and malware. I would like to build a malware detection system based on the assembly language used by these files, by using machine learning. The language that I would like to choose for extracting the assembly language is C++. I used objdump from Linux, but sometimes as a mnemonic, it is returned the word bad because it could not have been found.

Could you please suggest me packages in C++ that could help me to extract the assembly language of multiple files at the same time?

Comment: Capstone is fairly flexible: https://www.capstone-engine.org/

Comment: Look at LLVM-MC if you want a pure C++ implementation.  Capstore is implemented in C but does have C++ bindings, and is far far more flexible than LLVM-MC.  See http://www.capstone-engine.org/beyond_llvm.html